# Problem serializing JsonNode within micronaut controller response object

Tags: java, json, jackson, micronaut

I've used a jackson ObjectMapper to parse some text JSON to a JsonNode (using `readTree`). I can print out the pretty printed string and it all looks good.

If that JsonNode is on an object returned by a micronaut controller though, then I'm not seeing any of the fields. I just get the object and array structure. Seems odd, what am I missing?

```
[
            [
                [],
                [],
                [
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ],
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ],
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ],
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [],
                [],
                [
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [],
                [],
                [
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [],
                [],
                [
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                [],
                [],
                [
                    [
                        [],
                        []
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to change the controller return type to `String` and return `jsonNode.toString()`, which seems to work.

```java
package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
```

It seems the problem is related to

```
JsonNode implements Iterable<JsonNode>
```

and micronaut does not pick up the correct serializer for `JsonNode`.